# "Translate" tab does not appear for every content

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have installed the Localization module in my drupal project. All was working fine until now but i just noticed the "Translate" tab isn't visible for all my contents...

What i'm doing is simply :

-I go to content management
-content
-edit

-> Translate tab isn't visible...

On the other hand, when i try to translate another content of another content type, translate appears...

did anyone else face this problem previously?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The "Translate" tab is handled by the Translation module that comes with Drupal; the Internationalization module that handles the translation for nodes just overrides the page callback for that tab.

```php
function i18n_node_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/%node/translate'])) {
    $items['node/%node/translate']['page callback'] = 'i18n_node_translation_overview';
    $items['node/%node/translate']['file'] = 'i18n_node.pages.inc';
    $items['node/%node/translate']['module'] = 'i18n_node';
  }
  // Take over node/add pages for string translation
  $items['node/add']['page callback'] =  'i18n_node_add_page';
  $items['node/add']['file'] = 'i18n_node.pages.inc';
  $items['node/add']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'i18n_node');
  // @TODO avoid iterating over every router path.
  foreach (node_type_get_types() as $type) {
    $path = 'node/add/' . str_replace('_', '-', $type->type);
    if (isset($items[$path])) {
      $items[$path]['title callback'] = 'i18n_node_type_name';
      $items[$path]['title arguments'] = array($type->type, $type->name);
    }
  }
}
```

In order to have that tab visible for a node, the multilingual support for the content type must be set to *Enabled, with translation*.

In Drupal 8, that is done in `admin/structure/types/manage/<content type ID>`, but the option is titled *Enable translation*. The route is defined from the *Content Translation* module, which must be installed.

> [image: screenshot]

In Drupal 7, that is done in `admin/structure/types/manage/<content type ID>`.

> [image: screenshot]

In Drupal 6, it is done in `admin/content/node-type/<content type ID>`.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: in my site enabled with translation is marked, and the translation tab is missing for some nodes. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: maybe node language is `Language neutral`, try to set as English then Translate tab will appear