# How to displaying translate tab in the node

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, nodes, forms

I have Multilingual and internalization Module installed on a Drupal installation. I need to have the translate link option on every node as the following screenshot:

[image]

Also I need if the content (node) in some language has no translated version in other language, when clicking to the language choose bar, it go to the default home page in the other language or Page Not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tab does show when:

1. You have more than one language installed. **Locale** module needs to be enabled.
2. You have **Content Translation** or **Entity Translation** modules enabled (not **i18n**)
3. You have set up the content to be translatable, in the the content type settings page (if it's a node). When using Entity Translation, prior to that, you should define the entity type (e.g. node) to be translatable.
4. Your user has permissions to translate content.

Comment: See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/50958/10086